# train_test_split affect result when predict value the same

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm new in data science, I have a question about `train_test_split`.

I have a example try to predict ice tea sales from temperature

My Question is when I use `train_test_split`, my mse, score & predict sales value will be different every times (since `train_test_split` selected different part every times)

Is this normal? If user enter 30 degree same value every time and they will get different predict sales value?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#1. predict value
temperature = np.reshape(np.array([30]), (1, 1))

#2. data
X = np.array([29, 28, 34, 31, 25, 29, 32, 31, 24, 33, 25, 31, 26, 30]) #temperatures
y = np.array([77, 62, 93, 84, 59, 64, 80, 75, 58, 91, 51, 73, 65, 84]) #iced_tea_sales

X = np.reshape(X, (len(X), 1))
y = np.reshape(y, (len(y), 1))

#3. split data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)

#4. train
lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X_train, y_train)

#5. mse score
y_pred = lm.predict(X_test)
mse = np.mean((y_pred - y_test) ** 2)
r_squared = lm.score(X_test, y_test)

print(f'mse: {mse}')
print(f'score(r_squared): {r_squared}')

#6. predict
sales = lm.predict(temperature)
print(sales) #output, user get their prediction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values will never be the same as when you fit() any model even on the same data multiple times, the weights learned may vary hence the predictions can never be the same. Though, they should be close enough (if you don't have outliers)  as the distribution from which the samples are coming is common.

Comment: 1 more question, should I keep add/update my data frame and tune it  to improve my model?

Comment: No!! changing your data constantly won't give you an idea which model performed better. You must always keep your data constant whenever tuning your parameters.

Comment: if I dont update new data, how can I improve my machine learning, this model may not accuracy after 10 years.

Comment: Consider this. Suppose you wish to deploy a model for some classification. Than, while deciding over the model for that particular time, you will be testing out multiple models , params. Right? at that time when you compare multiple models, use a constant dataset. Suppose you observed your model isn't performing well. This can mean the distribution has changed. Now to update the model, you will again make a constant dataset from changed distribution & check against multiple models